# Component loading results in "Module name has not been loaded yet for context"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, requirejs

I'm trying to learn more about Vue.js, but I'm fighting with a problem. I'm trying to use .vue files so I can have my template code inside this file. My html code looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <navbar-component></navbar-component>
    </div>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And my working JavaScript / Vue.js code look like this.

```
Vue.component('navbar-component', {
  template: '<h3>Title</h3>'
});

const demo = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted');
  }
});
```

The problem is when I change it to use this JavaScript. When I try to load from my test.vue file, it does not work anymore and I get this error.

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "src/components/test.vue" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (require.js:1436)
    at requirejs (require.js:1797)
    at main.js:1
```

My final test code looke like this:

**main.js**

```
Vue.component('navbar-component', require('./src/components/test.vue'));

const demo = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted');
  }
});
```

**src/components/test.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="helloworld">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with RequireJS, but I imagine you'll need some plugin to make it work with `.vue` files (e.g. [`requirejs-vue`](https://github.com/vikseriq/requirejs-vue)). Vue isn't typically used with RequireJS AFAIK, usually `.vue` files are *precompiled* as part of a webpack build (or similar) using [`vue-loader`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org).

Comment: Hmm, what i expect its shut be easy to code whitout node.js / npm, and can do its very easy i can't find enything about requirejs-vue and loader, did you have eny guide you can link?